# Parsing json with php from google api currency converter

Tags: php, json

I am trying to connect with Google API currency converter. Since it returns an invalid json response, I had to change the format. But now I am stuck on how to get the information out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
$amount = '100';
$from = 'USD';
$to = 'MXN';

// Make param to be sent in API
$string = $amount.$from."=?".$to;

// Call Google API
$google_url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=".$string;

// Get and Store API results into a variable
$result = file_get_contents($google_url);
$result = explode('"', $result);

$fromParts = explode(' ',  $result[1]);
$toParts = explode(' ',  $result[3]);

$return = array(
    'from' => array(
        'code' => $from,
        'amount' => cleanAmount($fromParts[0])
    ),
    'to' => array(
        'code' => $to,
        'amount' => cleanAmount($toParts[0])
    )
);

$json = json_encode($return);
//echo json_encode($return);
```

The response I get is this:

```
{"from":{"code":"USD","amount":100},"to":{"code":"MXN","amount":1304.80167}}
```

And I am trying to extract the to->amount, but I am getting an empty result.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'to'};
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/olympust/public_html/lista-traslados-mexico.php on line 101
```

Anyone have any idea how to get the variables from response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `echo` an object. You can do either:

```
echo $obj->to->amount; // prints the value
```

or

```
print_r($obj->to); // prints the object
```